Make an element sticky until a specific amount of the remaining container height is reached
How can an element be defined to behave like a sticky element only when the remaining height of the element is greater than a specific size (that I will call sticky container margin)?
For example, in the below image:

You can see that the light blue container has a sticky red element, and the sticky container margin is showed as a dark blue line. When the container element is leaving the screen, the red element stays sticky until the sticky container margin reaches the end of the container.
Here is an initial code to try out some solutions. I tried to make the blue line a container, but that messes up the initial position of the rest of the content.


section {
  height: 300lvh;
}

.content {
  background: #eee;
  height: 80lvh;
}

.box {
  height: 120lvh;
  background: #9f9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  height: 20lvh;
  background: #99f;
}

.end {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.flex-end {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
<section>
  <div class="content">Prev content</div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="sticky">
      Sticky element
    </div>
    <div>
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="flex-end">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content end">
    When this is visible, the sticky element should go up
  </div>
</section>




I am looking for a CSS-only solution, but if there's a solution with JS that is simple and performant, I would accept it while no CSS-only solution is available.

Added some content divs to the given code, which correspond to the small blue boxes shown in the image.

The dark blue line isn’t really the remaining height (or the “sticky container margin”), but calculating that would require the size of the sticky red element, which would probably only be possible with JS (with ResizeObserver).

I would play with some margin


section {
  height: 300lvh;
}

.content {
  background: #eee;
  height: 80lvh;
}

.box {
  height: 120lvh;
  background: #9f9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  height: 20lvh;
  margin-bottom: 80lvh; /* here */
  background: #99f;
}

.sticky + * {
  margin-top: -80lvh; /* and here */
}

.end {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.flex-end {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
<section>
  <div class="content">Prev content</div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="sticky">
      Sticky element
    </div>
    <div>
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="flex-end">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content end">
    When this is visible, the sticky element should go up
  </div>
</section>




One solution is to use a wrapper for the sticky content. The concept is to have a smaller container to start being scrolled out of view when content end comes in.
You don't need Javascript if the height of the sticky element is hard-coded (20lvh in your case), or else you will need to use Javascript to get the height of the sticky element.
.box {
  --sticky-height: 20lvh;
  height: 120lvh;
  background: #9f9;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100lvh + var(--sticky-height));
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-container {
  position: relative;
  top: var(--sticky-height);
  height: calc(100% - var(--sticky-height));
  /*The css for laying out the contents originally in box needs to be moved here*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

As shown in below example:


section {
  height: 300lvh;
}

.content {
  background: #eee;
  height: 80lvh;
}

.box {
  --sticky-height: 20lvh;

  height: 120lvh;
  background: #9f9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  height: var(--sticky-height);
  background: #99f;
}

.end {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.flex-end {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sticky-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100lvh + var(--sticky-height));
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-container {
  position: relative;
  top: var(--sticky-height);
  height: calc(100% - var(--sticky-height));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
<section>
  <div class="content">Prev content</div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="sticky-wrapper">
      <div class="sticky">
        Sticky element
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
      content
      <div class="flex-end">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content end">
    When this is visible, the sticky element should go up
  </div>
</section>




That doesn't seem to work. Where would the content of the box be placed?
If the additional content of the box is placed outside the sticky wrapper, there would be a gap between the content and the sticky element.

That is true, I did not consider additional contents. But it should be a fairly easy fix adding a margin top. Let me fix it.

I've updated the solution to match your example code, though I do think Temani's  margin bottom is probably better since there's no need to modify the parent element.
